# Best way to instantiate an object with every key equal to null?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

So in my React project, I have a fallback default state for an address form that looks like this:

```
state = {
  newLocation: this.props.location || {
    lat: null,
    lng: null,
    street: null,
    complement: null,
    neighbourhood: null,
    city: null,
    state: null,
    zipCode: null,
    country: null,
  },
}
```

However, it feels quite ridiculous defining such a large object with all keys equal to null. Is there a shorter way of doing this? Something in ES6/ES7?

Comment: Do they absolutely need to be explicitly set to `null`? Can't whatever code that uses these properties just accept `undefined` as an empty value so that you can just have: `newLocation: this.props.location || {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array and iterate the keys and build a new object with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var keys = ['lat', 'lng', 'street', 'complement', 'neighbourhood', 'city', 'state', 'zipCode', 'country'],
    loc = { lat: 123, lng: 246, city: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    state = {
        newLocation: Object.assign(keys.reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: null }), {}), loc)
    };

console.log(state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use defaultProps method

> defaultProps can be defined as a property on the component class itself, to set the default props for the class. This is used for undefined props, but not for null props. For example:

```
class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

CustomButton.defaultProps = {
  color: 'blue'
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I mean, you'd still have to explicitly set all those properties to null anyway.

Comment: Then just let it be undefined if you dint want to set it one by one